# Converting CSV to JSON with pandas but need specific format

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, formatting

I am wanting to convert an unconventional CSV format into a JSON file with a very specific format. I am not allowed to edit the CSV itself in order to help the problem, and must use pandas to extract the CSV data.

My CSV look something like this (smaller version):

| ID | Name | Exam name 1 | Exam mark 1 | Exam name 2 | Exam mark 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | John Smith | Computing | 72 | Maths | 90 |
| 124 | Amy Smith | History | 12 | Maths | 46 |

The CSV is much longer that this with 32 exam name and mark entries.

I need my JSON to look like this:

```json
{
    "Students": [
            {
                "123":{
                "Name": "John Smith",
                "Marks": [
                {
                  "Exam Name": "Computing"
                  "Exam Mark": 72
                },
                {
                  "Exam Name": "Maths"
                  "Exam Mark": 90
                }
              ]
            },
            {
                "124":{
                "Name": "Amy Smith",
                "Marks": [
                {
                  "Exam Name": "History"
                  "Exam Mark": 12
                },
                {
                  "Exam Name": "Maths"
                  "Exam Mark": 46
                }
              ]
            },
etc...
```

Please can someone help :)

```py
data = {} 
stu = data["Student"] = []

df=pd.read_csv(csvFilePath,usecols=[0, 1])
stu.append(df.set_index('id').T.to_dict('dicts'))
```

gives:

```
{
    "Student": [
        {
            "123": {
                  "Name": "John Smith"
            },
            "124": {
                  "Name": "Amy Smith"
            },
```

How do I then add the marks to look like the example at the top?

I know I can access specific columns by number, but I do not know how to loop through them and add them into the correct place in my json file.

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [123, 124],
        "Name": ["John Smith", "Amy Smith"],
        "Exam name 1": ["Computing", "History"],
        "Exam mark 1": [72, 12],
        "Exam name 2": ["Maths", "Maths"],
        "Exam mark 2": [90, 46],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```py
stu = {"Students": []}

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    stu["Students"].append(
        {
            row["ID"]: {
                "Name": row["Name"],
                "Marks": [
                    {
                        "Exam Name": row[f"Exam name {i}"],
                        "Exam Mark": row[f"Exam mark {i}"],
                    }
                    for i in range(1, 3)
                ],
            }
        }
    )
```

Then:

```py
print(stu)
# Output

{'Students': [{123: {'Name': 'John Smith',
                     'Marks': [{'Exam Name': 'Computing', 'Exam Mark': 72},
                               {'Exam Name': 'Maths', 'Exam Mark': 90}]}},
              {124: {'Name': 'Amy Smith',
                     'Marks': [{'Exam Name': 'History', 'Exam Mark': 12},
                               {'Exam Name': 'Maths', 'Exam Mark': 46}]}}]}
```